# Error when on dynamically inserted nodes in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to make an scenario in OMNeT with different Areas. Each area is a compound module which have many nodes inside, such like a city or something like that. I want that nodes moves from one area to another.
I already done that, but the nodes that are dynamically inserted in their new areas throws error when they are going to perform a transmission.
The error is not throwed in all transmissions, just sometimes.
I debugged my code and the error is in Signal.cc file, seems that node doesn't find the radioMediumModule. I'm using IEE802.15.4 communications and SensorNode module.
I think thay maybe is an allocation of memory problem, since the error does not always throw.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already solved this issue. The solution is modify the Signal.cc module. I changed the line radioMedium(transmission->getTransmitter()->getMedium()) in the first constructor by: radioMedium(transmission->getMedium()) and that's all. I assume that a memory access error was arising.

Comment: Important note: My simulation have many areas, where each area has its own radioMedium module. Maybe that was causing overflow in any variable. Anyways, I solved the issue with the change in my previous comment. I hope be useful for someone.